# Additive images in Unity script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I'm making a script that renders a scene frame by frame in Unity and overlays each frame on the previous one. It turns out motion blur. The frame is then saved. And the problem begins. Th problem is that after overlaying pictures, artifacts appear on the final image.

There are two frames in the picture below: on the left - a normal image consisting of one frame(1 iteration of motion blur), on the right - an image with an overlay of 10 previous frames (10 iterations of motion blur).

[Image with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVUME.jpg)

As if the color depth changes after overlays.

This is the code of the function that is responsible for overlaying frames:

```
//VFB is a video frame buffer. It is a type of Texture2D. 
//It is clearing after storing each frame.

//MoBlur_Steps int, the number of motion blur iterations.

   void Fill_VFB(Texture2D src)
    {
        UnityEngine.Color32[] src_pixels = src.GetPixels32();
        UnityEngine.Color32[] dest_pixels = VFB.GetPixels32();

        for (int i = 0; i < src_pixels.Length; i++)
        {
            dest_pixels[i].r = (byte)(dest_pixels[i].r + (float)src_pixels[i].r / MoBlur_Steps);
            dest_pixels[i].g = (byte)(dest_pixels[i].g + (float)src_pixels[i].g / MoBlur_Steps);
            dest_pixels[i].b = (byte)(dest_pixels[i].b + (float)src_pixels[i].b / MoBlur_Steps);
            dest_pixels[i].a = (byte)(dest_pixels[i].a + (float)src_pixels[i].a / MoBlur_Steps);
        }

        VFB.SetPixels32(dest_pixels);
        Render_Step++;
    }
```

I tried to make this with type Color. Then I thought that it was a rounding error when dividing the color components and tried to do the same with type double for each component of color, but results was identical.

Need help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should need to blend two pixels instead of add them.
Another point to note is that converting a float to byte may overflow.

```
float f = 1f / MoBlur_Steps;
float t = dest_pixels[i].r * (1-f) + src_pixels[i].r * f;
dest_pixels[i].r = t >= 255f ? (byte)255 : (byte)t;
```

Blending alpha channel is a bit special, usually if the current pixel is opaque, you expect the pixel to keep opaque after blending, so your original method can work.

```
t = dest_pixels[i].a + src_pixels[i].a * f;
dest_pixels[i].a = t >= 255f ? (byte)255 : (byte)t;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved the problem. But the picture became much darker.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you adjusted the brightness of the original texture? Or is the texture semi transparent? Blending should not change the brightness.

Comment: Yes. The texture contains transparency. And I am working with alpha channel too.

Comment: Try not doing the same job to the alpha channel.

Comment: But I need to process all the channels in the image. I also need an alpha channel with motion blur. I managed to solve this problem by dividing MoBlur_Steps by 2. And for 10 iterations, the code works perfectly! But I haven't tried testing it on other iteration settings yet.

Comment: I mean you can use your original method to process the alpha channel, I've updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did that and even changed my function to type Color(floating point), but the picture still came out too dark. But after doing this: float f = 1f / MoBlur_Steps / 2; the picture looks normal.